# Network Game testing via Wireshark

Tags: performance, testing, networking, benchmarking, wireshark

How can i check/inspect the performance of my network game via **Wireshark** and specifically the Graphs available in *Wireshark*,i want to test the performance of my network game. which kind of graphs can be helpful and give me the idea of network performance of my game? i m really newbie to networking so i m unable to decide.

any ideas,

thanks,

Jibbylala

Comment: What kinda of things are you looking to find out?

Comment: any kind of thing which can tell me about the performance and possible problem areas of game related to networking.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the options under the **Statistics** menu, particularly the **Conversations** menu, which will give you an idea of the amount and types of traffic between the hosts that you are logging. This is a good starting point for figuring out the filters you need to make to filter out your application's traffic.

Next I would look at learning your way around the **IO Graphs** feature. This is a very powerful tool for visualizing what is going on (particularly when using the Advanced.. option for the y-axis).

Once you have this figured out you can start diving into the details of your applications protocol. You'll get plenty of help on here if you can ask specific questions and provide sample capture logs.

Comment: i see the Throughput and RoundTriptime and other graphs, the problem i m facing and ambiguity i have is that; are those graphs reflecting or are they based on the data of my application or they are based on the overall network performance and data of that host/machine and if they how to set or how to get the graphs reflecting only my application relevant information current i m filtering the port and ip of my client but still confused that server is showing the graph of that client to/from traffic or of overall traffic.

Comment: I suggest that you post your capture file  - it would then be easier to make some suggestions

Comment: its not a simple question because you haven't provided any information about the network protocols your game is using, or what kind of performance metrics you are looking for. That is why posting an example capture would help.